# spring amqp stop consumer threads in case of broker crash

Tags: spring-amqp

I am trying to shutdown the entire amqp setup in case of a broker failure WITHOUT shutting down the context/application. I have tried the following from a Listener where I capture the events related to connection errors from broker failure,

```
 connectionFactory.clearConnectionListeners();
 connectionFactory.stop();
 connectionFactory.destroy();
 myContainer.stop();  
 myContainer.shutdown();
```

However, I keep getting the connection reattempts,

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:309)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1368)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1344)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:335)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1278)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
```

Looking into CachingConnectionFactory, I see this,

```
/**
 * Stop the connection factory to prevent its connection from being used.
 * Note: ignored unless the application context is in the process of being stopped.
 */
@Override
public void stop() {
    if (this.contextStopped) {
        this.running = false;
        this.stopped = true;
        this.deferredCloseExecutor.shutdownNow();
    }
    else {
        logger.warn("stop() is ignored unless the application context is being stopped");
    }
}
```

Which is what I see in my logs when I try to stop the connectionFactory,

```
WARN --- [onsumerThread_8] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory : stop() is ignored unless the application context is being stopped
```

so does this mean, I have to shutdown the application? Is there no way that the app can continue running without the endless connection attempts from consumer threads to broker?

thanks

**EDIT**

ok, the EventListener works as expected and I am able to shutdown the listenerContainers and the app continues to work fine.
But this approach is biting me on startup.
This works fine while the app is running and then I shut down the broker. But the app fails to start because on startup on receiving the failures, the EventListener shuts down the container and the application context refuses to load. 
Does this make sense?

How can I achieve both these objectives - 1. on startup, 2. during running, make the app withstand the loss of broker.?

*`EDIT`*
The approach to capture the failure events worked to circumvent the broker failure during runtime as suggested by @garyrussel and @artembilan. Just shutting down the MessageListenerContainer seemed to stop the consumer reconnect attempts. The event listener gave me the ability to update a global variable to communicate the failure of broker to other modules in the system. This was important since the producer, which just uses rabbitTemplate would still fail otherwise. Using this global boolean var, I could conditionally do a send.
It also gave us the option in future to add a REST endpoint to restart the ListenerContainers by simply calling `start` on the beans.
I haven't gotten around to fixing the startup time failure of rabbitMQ. It seemed that having a `@Lazy` loading of ListenerContainer and ConnectionFactory may be the way to go. But haven't tried it out.
thanks much for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest your concern is absolutely unclear. Doing `clearConnectionListeners`, `destroy` and `shutdown` you make your components as dead and useless in the future when Rabbit Broker comes back.

What you need is only to `stop()` all Listener Container, because only they do an active attempt to connect to broker for new messages.

Please, be sure that you really stop all the Listener Containers in your application. And, of course, don't stop `ConnectionFactory`. You won't be able to restore when Broker comes back.

Looks like fully related to your question: [spring amqp rabbit max consumer connection retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377113/spring-amqp-rabbit-max-consumer-connection-retries)

Comment: If you are using discrete SimpleMessageListenerContainer beans, just `stop()` them; if you are using `@RabbitListener`, `@Autowire` the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` and `stop()` it and it will stop all its registered listeners.